# How to find the duplicates in the given string in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to find the duplicates for a given string, I tried for collections, It is working fine, but i don't know how to do it for a string.

Here is the code I tried for collections,

```
string name = "this is a a program program";
string[] arr = name.Split(' ');

var myList = new List<string>();
var duplicates = new List<string>();

foreach(string res in arr)
{
    if (!myList.Contains(res))
    {
        myList.Add(res);
    }
    else
    {
        duplicates.Add(res);
    }
}

foreach(string result in duplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

But I want to find the duplicates for the below string and to store it in an array. How to do that?

```
eg:- string aa = "elements";
```

In the above string i want to find the duplicate characters and store it in an array

Can anyone help me?

Comment: your code works fine to find the duplicates. What do you mean by your question? Do you mean find if `"elements"` is a duplicate word? If so, just check `if(duplicates.Contains("elements")){}` after you have built your duplicate list

Comment: string a = "elements" => here i want to find a duplicate character and store it in an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        string name = "elements";
        var myList = new List<char>();
        var duplicates = new List<char>();

        foreach (char res in name)
        {
            if (!myList.Contains(res))
            {
                myList.Add(res);
            }
            else if (!duplicates.Contains(res))
            {
                duplicates.Add(res);
            }
        }

        foreach (char result in duplicates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

*Linq* solution:

```
  string name = "this is a a program program";

  String[] result = name.Split(' ')
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() > 1)
    .Select(chunk => chunk.Key)
    .ToArray();

  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

The same princicple for duplicate *characters* within a *string*:

```
 String source = "elements";

 Char[] result = source
   .GroupBy(c => c)
   .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() > 1)
   .Select(chunk => chunk.Key)
   .ToArray();

 // result = ['e']
 Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `List<>` i'd use a `HashSet<>` because it doesn't allow duplicates and `Add` returns `false` in that case. It's more efficient. I'd also use a `Dictionary<TKey,Tvalue>` instead of the list to track the count of each char:

```
string text = "elements";
var duplicates = new HashSet<char>();
var duplicateCounts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (char c in text)
{
    int charCount = 0;
    bool isDuplicate = duplicateCounts.TryGetValue(c, out charCount);
    duplicateCounts[c] = ++charCount;
    if (isDuplicate)
        duplicates.Add(c);
}
```

Now you have all unique duplicate chars in the `HashSet` and the count of each unique char in the dictionary. In this example the set only contains `e` because it's three times in the string.

So you could output it in the following way:

```
foreach(char dup in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate char {0} appears {1} times in the text."
                     , dup
                     , duplicateCounts[dup]);
```

---

For what it's worth, here's a LINQ one-liner which also creates a `Dictionary` that only contains the duplicate chars and their count:

```
Dictionary<char, int> duplicateCounts = text
            .GroupBy(c => c)
            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

I've shown it as second approach because you should first understand the standard way.

Answer (score 2):

string is an array of chars. So, you can use your collection approach.
But, I would reccomend typed HashSet. Just load it with string and you'll get array of chars without duplicates, with preserved order.

take a look:

```
  string s = "aaabbcdaaee";
  HashSet<char> hash = new HashSet<char>(s);
  HashSet<char> hashDup = new HashSet<char>();
  foreach (var c in s)
    if (hash.Contains(c))
      hash.Remove(c);
    else
      hashDup.Add(c);
  foreach (var x in hashDup)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
  Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Very neat idea - but which are the duplicates?

Comment: Mottor kindly suggested improvement

Answer (score 0):

```
        string name = "this is a a program program";
        var arr = name.Split(' ').ToArray();
        var dup = arr.Where(p => arr.Count(q => q == p) > 1).Select(p => p);
        HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>(dup);
        string duplicate = string.Join(" ", hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through `LINQ

```
string name = "this is a a program program";
var d = name.Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x).Select(y => new { word = y.Key, Wordcount = y.Count() }).Where(z=>z.cou > 1).ToList();
```

Comment: No need for the intermediate WordCount, just `name.Split(' ').GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() > 1).Select(z => z.Key).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ to group values:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
  return list.GroupBy(item => item).SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1));
}

public static bool HasDuplicates<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    return list.GetDuplicates().IsNotEmpty();
}
```

Then you use these extensions like this:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "b", "c" };
var duplicatedValues = list.GetDuplicates();
```